# How to make lottie animation of image sequance by python?

Tags: python, lottie

I am trying to make animation using lottie frame work in python. The script I have made can show only one image. I don't know how to animate image sequence in lottie frame work by python. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from lottie.utils import script
from lottie import objects
from lottie import Point, Color
import os



image_filename1 = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/images1/pngImages'+'/'+'2020-05-01'+"_new.png"


last_frame = 60
an = objects.Animation(last_frame, 1)

an.width = 720
an.height = 360
image1 = objects.assets.Image().load(image_filename1)
an.assets.append(image1)

an.add_layer(objects.ImageLayer(image1.id))

script.script_main(an, path="/Users/ihasan/", basename='sample2', formats=['html'])
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching on the lottie-python examples script [here](http://mattia.basaglia.gitlab.io/python-lottie/examples.html), I found a way to animate image sequence. The code I am sharing here is composed of two image. It can be simplified using a loop with more image.

```
from lottie.utils import script
from lottie import objects
from lottie import Point, Color
import os

image_filename1 = "/../" # image1 directory
image_filename2 = "/../" # image2 directory


image1 = objects.assets.Image().load(image_filename1)
image2 = objects.assets.Image().load(image_filename2)

lastFrame = 60
an = objects.Animation(lastFrame)
an.width = 720
an.height = 360

an.assets.append(image1)
an.assets.append(image2)

precomp = objects.Precomp("myid", an)
layer1 = objects.ImageLayer(image1.id)

layer1.out_point = 20

precomp.add_layer(layer1)

pcl0 = an.add_layer(objects.PreCompLayer("myid"))
pcl0.width = 720
pcl0.height = 360

pcl0.start_time = 0

layer2 = objects.ImageLayer(image2.id)
layer2.out_point = 40
precomp.add_layer(layer2)

pcl1 = an.add_layer(objects.PreCompLayer("myid"))
pcl1.start_time = 20
pcl1.width = 720
pcl0.height = 360

script.script_main(an, path="../../", basename='samplePrecomp', formats=['json'])
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging-in in the ['documentation'](https://mattbas.gitlab.io/python-lottie/index.html) I figured out how generate a lottie starting from a set of images.
Here every image stays for one frame only, but can be adapted if needed:

```py
from lottie.utils import script
from lottie import objects
import glob

ANIMATION_WIDTH = 752
ANIMATION_HEIGHT = 715


def make_lottie_from_images(images_folder, image_format='png'):
    images = glob.glob(f"{images_folder}/*.{image_format}")
    animation = objects.Animation(len(images), 60) # every image is a frame, so len(images) frames for 60fps

    animation.width = ANIMATION_WIDTH
    animation.height = ANIMATION_HEIGHT

    for frame, image in enumerate(images):
        img = objects.assets.Image().load(image)
        animation.assets.append(img)
        layer = objects.ImageLayer(img.id)
        ly = animation.add_layer(layer)
        ly.in_point = frame
        ly.out_point = frame+1 # every image stays for one frame only

    script.script_main(animation, path="./out",
                       basename='out', formats=['json'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    frame_folder = "path/to/all/images"
    make_lottie_from_images(frame_folder)
```